# PayPal dynamic price

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've done a LOT of research on how to accept payments through PayPal for items whose price changes dynamically.

My site sells a service and there are pretty much an infinite possible prices for the same item based on parameters (price increments in $0.99, 0.20 and 0.10).

1. I've looked into Paypal Express but it doesn't seem to allow accepting credit cards / debit cards, only payments through Paypal.
2. I looked into a "hacky" solution that calls the API's BMUpdateButton method to update the price of the button on PayPal's side but this won't work in my case as multiple users may be on the page at the same time and would need to be quoted different prices.
3. I saw that I can create a payment page from scratch and call APIs to create, accept, and verify payments against PayPal but that's a lot of coding for one and that tremendously reduces security as I don't have SSL and will need to get it which isn't cheap for a start-up business :)
4. I also came across creating a "non-hosted" button (haven't tried it yet) but that seems to require specifying my business email address in the HTML code which would be far less than ideal.

What I'd really like to do is have a php page act as a gatekeeper between the time the user checks out and what gets sent to PayPal where my PHP can inject the payment amount in and the user can confirm it on the PayPal page and checkout. Any other solution that satisfy the requirements will be truly appreciated.

Requirements again are

1. Must accept credit cards and PayPal payments
2. User does not have to have a Paypal account
3. Price must be dynamic and be able to support multiple users at the same time
4. Must be as secure as possible. I don't have SSL. An html input type='hidden' won't work as it's too easy to manipulate.

Another thing I thought of just now while typing this post up - if I can securely add quantities of an "item" that may also serve the purpose. For instance, I could add 10 quantities of "items" costing $0.99 and 2 "items" costing 0.10 to get to my required total of 10.19. Is it possible? The quantity boxes, again, must not be changeable by the user. It's more of an all or nothing type of deal :)

Help will be truly appreciated. Please let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment: Have you considered PayPal Payments Pro?

Comment: Hi Machavity. Thanks for the reply! That looks quite promising as it seems to offer "Design and host your own checkout pages for full control" capability over the Basic and Advanced Paypal Payment solutions. Does that mean I *HAVE* to host the checkout page? That may mean I absolutely have to get SSL for my site.

Comment: In a nutshell, yes. You would have to host all the transaction pages (SSL) and then make your API calls on the backend. but it would afford you complete control over the process.

If the monthly fee for Pro is a turnoff, consider [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) instead. More expensive for higher volumes but no monthly fee.

Comment: +1 for stripe. That looks like a solution I can definitely use on my site. I'll also get SSL certificates for my site. There doesn't seem to be any way around that if I am to keep transactions secure. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Checkout does include "Guest Checkout" so people can pay using a credit card without having or creating a PayPal account.  Unfortunately, they just recently made changes so you're forced to click a "Guest Checkout" button before you can see the full credit card form, so some buyers still miss it and don't realize they can do that.

Payments Pro would definitely give you want, but you would indeed need an SSL, and you'd need to make sure you're not saving any credit card details locally.

Payments Advanced is similar to Pro except that the form is hosted within an iframe and resides on PayPal's server so you don't need an SSL that way.

I personally prefer Payments Pro.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I completely missed the fact that I'll need SSL either way or data from the client to my site isn't encrypted and is open to packet sniffing. I may need to start off with Payments Advanced just for the lower monthly price and once sales pick up I'll upgrade to Payments Pro. Does Payments Advanced allow API calls? Information I've come across so far seems to suggest API calls are only available on Payments Pro.